# Adding multiple items to an array with separations

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a tableView with cells of products, and when a cell is selected I want the name of the cell to be added to another array and be separated with `""` and `,`

The array for the tableView is `"a", "b", "c"` etc..

```
var name = ""
var arrayOfNames = ""
```

tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  name = sections[indexPath.section].productName[indexPath.row]
  arrayOfNames += name
  print(arrayOfNames)
}
```

So when the cell is pressed it's printing `"abc"` whereas I want `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the names in an actual array not a string and then use the plain and simple Swift [`print(_:separator:terminator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print)

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(array)
print(array, separator: ", ")
```

Comment: or `array.joined(separator: ", ")` which is more generic

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you’re simply changing the string `arrayOfNames` by adding each name to it. Therefore, there is no `”` nor `,` being added. You may want to try:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  name = sections[indexPath.section].productName[indexPath.row]
  if(arrayOfNames == “”) {
nameToAdd = “\”“+ name + “\””
  arrayOfNames += name
} else {
nameToAdd = “, \”“+ name + “\””
  arrayOfNames += nameToAdd
}
  print(arrayOfNames)
}
```

As you can see there, we are first building a string that contains the name between quotes (and the comma) and then only add it to the final string.

Comment: Hi GCourtet, Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Ivan Just did, thanks for letting me know that my answer lacked explanations.